# Class copies NSArray of other class and owns it distinctly

Tags: objective-c

I want to make sure I understand a key concept of properties and instance variable ownership of a class, in this case using NSArray.

Suppose I pass a reference to an `NSArray` to another class, and set that class's iVar to it. For example:

**First Technique**

`OtherClass.h`

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * otherClassArray;`

then:

`CurrentClass.m`

`otherclass.otherClassArray=myArray`

Now, even though `OtherClass` is retaining `myArray`, if `CurrentClass` changes `myArray` then `otherclass.otherClassArray` will also change, correct?

So, is this the better way to do it, or am I mistaken and the above will do what I'd expect from the following anyway:

**Second Technique**

`CurrentClass.m`

`otherclass.otherClassArray=[NSArray arrayWithArray:myArray]`

Now there is a distinct copy being made so any changes to `myArray` have no effect on `otherClassArray`, am I right, or are both of these approaches doing the same thing?

**UPDATE**: Is there any reason why my second technique above should or should not be used vs. using `copy` with the property? It would seem that either technique results in a new NSArray that my class owns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain) is [generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849942/nsarray-property-copy-or-retain) recommended [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579628/603977) properties whose classes have mutable subclasses (most notably, `NSString` and the various collection classes) be declared as `copy`:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * otherClassArray;
```

Then whenever you set the property, `OtherClass` will get its own version of the array.

Your second technique has the same result as declaring a `copy` property, yes, but it should be left up to the property's owner whether it wants a copy or not. To put it another way, the principle of *encapsulation* demands that client code (`CurrentClass`) not be responsible for knowing that `OtherClass` needs to have its own version of the object. It's a matter of design and maintainability.

Comment: I was using NSArray as an example, but suppose it was any kind of class, the question is the same; in my example, my class doesn't have its own copy of the object data unless it creates a new one, right?

Comment: put another way, by not using `copy` in the property, my second example would still give distinct object data to OtherClass, right?

Comment: Yes and yes; the key factor in deciding whether to use `copy` is, as I said, whether the class of the property has a mutable subclass.